# The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2017/03

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with not able to add images on media and also couldn't upload any images using customize in wordpress,
Here I am working on windows 8 OS and running my program on XAMPP server.
I checked too many solutions to fix this problem but nothing will happend. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check directory permissions

Comment: sorry I am new to wordpress, I don't know how to check directory permissions. Will you please say from where I check ?

Comment: I am sorry linux user here. No idea on win

Comment: it is okay @georoot